# Translating a C# Windows Form App to Python

Tags: c#, python

I wrote a Windows Form Application in C# for an Account Creation/Sign Up & Sign In/ Main Menu program that I am creating for a project I’m working on to build a custom gaming console for personal use. However, after spending 3 weeks working on the project in C#, I realized that the code must be done in Python. I would happily translate the code to Python, the problem is, I don’t know the first thing about the coding language. Any ideas for how I could easily translate the program to C#? I’ll post the code if necessary.

Comment: [Convert C# to Python](https://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-python/). However the UI technology and many other things might be different in Python. So converting just the syntax will solve the problem only partly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TheNetPlex!

I don´t know if that's possible because C# and Python are completely different programming languages.
Also, because you wrote a Windows Forms Applications, it means that you didn't use WPF so it is even harder to migrate the user interface.
I would try to make the application from the scratch in python. By doing that you would avoid some kind of compatibilities or weird issues.

Hope I've been useful! Good Luck!

Comment: Yes. @TheNetPlex: If you are in the lucky position to have a good separation between business logic and UI, then you might at least be able convert your code partly.

Comment: This helps, a lot, thanks! I’ll probably end up finding someone who knows Python and supplying the C# info to work together to recreate it in Python, as I don’t really have time to learn Python right now.  Any idea what the closest thing to a Windows Form App is in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and save your UI code by using ironpython, assuming you are using WPF. The downside is that it is only python 2.7 compatible